# In bxslider, how to set infiniteloop: false AND the # of slides = # of bullets?

Tags: jquery, bxslider

Adding "infiniteLoop: false" changes the number of bullets under a carousel.

Working from this bxslider example (with 10 slides and 10 bullets):
http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified#example4
on this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/_StephenC/s7KTk/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.slider4').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 300,
    minSlides: 2,
    maxSlides: 3,
    moveSlides: 1,
    slideMargin: 10,
   //infiniteLoop: false
  });
});
```

(one slide removed so there are 9 slides and 9 bullets)

All good until "infiniteloop:false", which removes one of the bullets.

Is there a way to have all 9 bullets show AND infiniteloop set to false?

(It's a client request: the 9th bullet will not move the carousel.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

http://jsfiddle.net/s7KTk/9/

```
Added empty div atlast.
```

Comment: Thanks. That adds and empty div, though, and we need it to stop on the last slide.

Comment: @StephenC - During the last click, 8th slider is moving little bit to left, do u want to stop it.  ie., no action during during last bullet click??

Comment: try this, http://jsfiddle.net/s7KTk/10/. I am not sure, this is right idea. :)  but, this does exactly what you need.

Comment: I still get an empty space there